# I am trying to create an windows application watcher?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I recently started coding in c #(in may this year) and well I find it best to learn by working with code. this application http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/satisharveti/ActiveApplicationWatcher01252007024921AM/ActiveApplicationWatcher.aspx.
I am trying to recreate it however mine will be saving the information into an sql database(new at this as well). I am having some coding problems though as it does not do what I expect it to do. THis is the main code I am using.

```
 private void GetTotalTimer()
    {
        //This gets the window that a user has open
        SqlConnection RConn = new SqlConnection(@"server=ANDILE-PC;Initial Catalog=Log Records;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
        string Connstring = RConn.ToString();
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        IntPtr hwnd = APIFunc.getforegroundWindow();
        Int32 pid = APIFunc.GetWindowProcessID(hwnd);
        Process p = Process.GetProcessById(pid);
        appName = p.ProcessName;
        string time = now.ToString();
        const int nChars = 256;
        int handle = 0;
        StringBuilder Buff = new StringBuilder(nChars);
        handle = GetForegroundWindow();

        appltitle = APIFunc.ActiveApplTitle().Trim().Replace("\0", "");
        string queryString = "Select Top 1[Window Title] FROM [TimerLogs]";
        using (RConn)
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = RConn.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = queryString;
                RConn.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string windowtitle = reader["Window Title"].ToString();
                        if (appltitle != windowtitle)
                        {

                            endTime = DateTime.Now;
                            appduration = endTime.Subtract(startTime);

                            cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into [TimerLogs] values (@time,@appName,@appltitle,@Elapsed_Time,@userName)", RConn);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", time);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@appName", appName);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@appltitle", appltitle);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Elapsed_Time", appduration.ToString());
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", userName);

                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            RConn.Close();

                        }

                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }

                RConn.Close();
            }

        }
    }
```

Unfortunately this is the result.
[image]
it is not saving the data as I expect it to. What am i doing wrong I had thought that with  the sql reader it would first check for a value and only save if they do not match however it is saving whether there is a match or not.

my reader is returning "{System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader}" instead of the data in the table

Comment: You need to learn to use your IDE's debugging features. Set a breakpoint, then step through the code line by line and see what it's doing.

Comment: your if (appltitle != reader.ToString()) condition always true check it properly

Comment: I'm new to both c# and sql so instead of just down-voting how about using some constructive criticism cause your votes help with nothing, I want to understand this language yet in trying to all i get are down-votes. How is that helpful if i made a mistake point it out blindly down-voting helps no one

Comment: One piece of advice that I can give you (not directly related to your problem) is to avoid `try` and `catch` for now. While you are developing code you **need** to let these exceptions happen so that you can see them and fix them so that they don't happen in the wild.

Comment: The main reason why i am using them is because the code runs from a timer and when i had used it the first time it nearly crashed my pc with errors

Comment: The code you posted will not “crashed my pc” and if it did `catch { }` would not fix it. Your code is full of mistakes and all `catch { }` does is prevent the OS from showing you the mistakes; they are still there. Never use `catch { }`, and learn to use a debugger.

Comment: As a long term SQL developer I'd advise you to name your columns and tables in such a way that you don't have to use square brackets.  For example WindowTitle instead of [Window Title].

Comment: How do the two differ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, we got three problems going on here. Let's focus on your bug first:

You are using `reader.ToString()` but that method does not what you think it does.

Look it up here -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx (you can reach that page and similiar pages by placing your cursor inside a type name and then pressing 'F1').

So, instead of your 'ToString()', you need to access the field you want to compare in a type-safe way by using `reader.GetString(0)`.

Second problem: Inside your `else if` block you are closing the SqlDataReader twice. That would throw an exception.

Now, off to the third problem:

Always use one connection object per SQL request. SQL connections are cached in .NET so you don't have to worry about timeloss and by doing that you also don't have to constantly check the state of your connection.

To make things easier, let me show you the magic of using statements:

```
using (SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
{
    myConn.Open();
    // execute first statement
}


using (SqlConnection myConn2 = new SqlConnection(connstring))
{
    myConn2.Open();
    // execute second statement
}
```

Part of a using statement is the declaration of the object you want to use. The object must be of type 'IDisposable'. Inside a using statement, the object is treated as a 'normal' object, for the most part at least. You can't change it's reference (meaning you can't assign a new SqlConnection to myConn2) but that's about it.

Things get more interesting when you leave a using statement. Regardless of how you leave it (return statement inside, an unhandled exception occured, or the program just continues on after having everything executed inside the using statement) the object will be disposed. And in case of a SqlConnection or a SqlDataReader, it's `Close()` method will also be called as part of the Dispose() implementation.

Comment: Ok but I want to get the last value in the window title column I had thought you use sqldatareader to get this information am i doing it wrong?

Comment: uh? We're talking about columns here, not rows. Your statement only returns one row and one field. To access the first row you already do everything neccessary (calling `Read()` once) now you need to access the first column for that record.

Comment: well the last row in the window title would be one value I am trying to use read but after using break points I found that it was not returning the values as i thought it was

Comment: @Broken_Code erh stop, you are confusing things ;) (or I'm misreading it). Execute your SQL statement on your SQL server, if it returns what it should return, everything should be fine). If not please edit your answer and add your current source code.

Comment: I am getting the last value as i should,when I execute it on the sql server

Comment: @Broken_Code ok. Now that's the exact same record your SqlDataReader will see, too. Meaning I'm not sure what your current problem is.

Comment: I wish i knew what the problem was also because I mean it works server side and i am sure i coded the reader properly yet it returns null while debugging and when i use tostring i get the System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader instead of the value

Comment: @Broken_Code could you please add your current code to your question?

Comment: @Broken_Code okay, please read my answer again, I had an error in the beginning and it seems you copied it. Please use `.GetString(0)` instead of [0].

Comment: I have tried using .GetString(0), my application now does not saving any data to the database. Can we create a discussion for this in 2 hours IF you are available I will be traveling and will not be able to access the internet for the next hour and half

Comment: @Broken_Code sorry not available. I'd advise you to clean up your code using the suggestions made by me (using statements) and Chris Haas, who advised the use of try/catch blocks. If it still fails after that, post your code again and describe the problem in your question.

Comment: I am now getting a result as per your suggestion i change the code however I am getting  'Exception Message "The ConnectionString property has not been initialized." string' that error which i am assuming is because I am miss using the "using" function with the connection string how do i correct this

Comment: @Broken_Code erh, your first using statement is wrong. `using (Conn)` should look like this: `using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))` also you forgot the curly braces for that using statement.

Comment: I had been using that but i already have the conn declared so i just used that instead of creating a new one

Comment: @Broken_Code that's not how it works ;). Also, as I said before: Use one `SqlConnection` / request. Your code is much easier to read and it's automatically threadsafe. (you won't believe how many problems I had because of people using one `SqlConnection` for everything)

Comment: I updated the code as you said however I am getting the following error "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0." I am assuming it does this becaues the connection was changed however  I am not sure why I tried looking through my code with breakpoints but found nothing

Comment: @Broken_Code you need to change `Conn.ToString()` to `Conn.ConnectionString`. The `ToString()` method, in most cases, is not to be used without checking what it actually returns. In most cases it returns a representation of the object.

Comment: Ok i have changed the connection string I added a new one and I am now able to connect to the database After running the code with multiple code breaks I am able to see each code. It works fine however when it loops over it does not work on the second loop. I know this is probably because I run it in the timer and I am not able to correctly close the sqldatareader as i was able to close the connection string.

Comment: @Broken_Code errh look closely at the loop and the `SqlCommand` object and think about what you are doing there combined with what I mentioned about how to handle sqlconnection objects...

Comment: @Broken_Code hint: You use one `SqlConnection` object for two (or more, depending on the amount of returned rows) actions/requests.

Comment: but i only use it once and the error i am getting is for the em sql command How can i take the data from the first sql connection and move it to another as all the information is needed

Comment: > but i only use it once

@Broken_Code no. Look at it. You use the same SqlConnection for the command and for the datareader. Also you close it after executing the SqlCommand. Which is exactly what you shouldn't do. A SqlDataReader needs an open connection as long as you are reading from it.

Comment: how can I run the sqlDatareader in a separate sql connection without losing the information from the first connection and without getting the " There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first." error

Comment: @Broken_Code what? Keep your hands off of your SqlDataReader, that thing is fine. Your SqlCommand that inserts stuff needs it's own SqlConnection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55824/discussion-between-broken-code-and-steffen-winkler).

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :** You are comparing the `appltitle`(i think string variable) with the SqlDataReader object. which will always gives you not equal and as you are inversing your result it willbe always true hence it stores the data into data irrespective of the situation.

**Solution:** You need to check the `appltitle`  variable with the proper column from the SELECT statement.

`reader[0]` gives you the `window title` from the Database(specified in SELECT statement)

Replace This:

```
if (appltitle != reader.ToString())
```

With This:

```
if (appltitle != reader[0].ToString())
```

Comment: How does that differ apart from the [0] I will try it just want to understand

Comment: @Broken_Code: reader[0] gives you the first parameter value from the SELECT statement which is `window title` ,check my edited answer.

Comment: I have tried using reader[0].ToString the results though have not changed. I also used break points and it still says System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader for my value instead of the last window title row value

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi while it is possible to do it like that, you should always try to use the type accessors to get a value. In this case `.GetString(0);` would be the clean way to do it.